# Redux mapStateToProps mismatches with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-redux

I have the following React component with TypeScript:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect, ConnectedProps} from 'react-redux';
import logo from './assets/logo.png';
// import { Counter } from './features/counter/Counter';
import './App.css';

import {IApplicationState} from './features/application/reducers';

const mapStateToProps = (application: IApplicationState) => {
  const applicationComposite = application.applicationComposite;

  return {applicationComposite};
}
const connector = connect(mapStateToProps);
type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>

interface Props extends PropsFromRedux {};

class App extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <span>
            <span>Attractora </span>
            {this.props.applicationComposite && <span>{this.props.applicationComposite.content}</span>}
          </span>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connector(App);
```

The problem is that I am getting `applicationComposite` as `undefined` even when the reducer's initial state has a value for it.

I debugged the code and found that `mapStateToProps(application: IApplicationState)` receives the value of `applicationComposite` in `application.application.applicationComposite`, but when I try to assign `applicationComposite = application.application.applicationComposite`, I get this error:

```
Property 'application' does not exist on type 'IApplicationState'.
```

I followed [this tutorial](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript#manually-typing-connect), but I can't find what I am doing wrong.

**EDIT**

This is my root reducer:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import application from '../features/application/reducers';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  application,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

And this is my application reducer:

```
import { Dictionary } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { ActionInterface } from '../generals';
import {
  FETCH_APPLICATION_COMPOSITE_SUCCESS,
  SET_CURRENT_APPLICATION_COMPONENT
} from './actions';

export interface IApplicationState {
  applicationComposite: any,
  currentApplicationComponent: string | null,
}

const INIT_STATE = {
  applicationComposite: {content: 'test_content'},
  currentApplicationComponent: null
}

export default (state=INIT_STATE, action: ActionInterface) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_APPLICATION_COMPOSITE_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        //@ts-ignore: Object is possibly 'undefined'
        applicationComposite: action.payload.applicationComposite
      }
    }
    case SET_CURRENT_APPLICATION_COMPONENT: {
      return {
        ...state,
        //@ts-ignore: Object is possibly 'undefined'
        currentApplicationComponent: action.payload.applicationComponent
      }
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show what the root and application reducers look like? It's hard to conceptualise because you've got the same name for two different levels of a state object.

Comment: @lawrence-witt I don't know where I am using the same name for two different objects, but I added the code you request to the body of the question. Thanks for taking the time

Comment: You are calling your root state `application` in MSTP, but then you have an `application` reducer directly on that. Paths like `application.application` are hard to reason about. As someone else has just answered, you are using an incorrect interface for your root state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, I think you are not using the root state type in the mapStateToProps function.

application is just part of the redux state so you cannot access application state directly in `mapStateToProps()`.
You should declare a root state type to be a central point of all states

```
export interface IRootState {
    application: IApplicationState
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers<IRootState>({
  application,
});
```

```
const mapStateToProps = (rootState: IRootState) => {
  const applicationComposite = rootState.application.applicationComposite;

  return {applicationComposite};
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but I just got a larger error: ` Type 'IApplicationState | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ applicationComposite: { name: string; label: string; }; currentApplicationComponent: null; } | undefined'.  TS2769

     7 | 
     8 | const rootReducer = combineReducers <IRootState> ({
  >  9 |   application,
       |   ^
    10 | });
    11 | 
    12 | export default rootReducer;
``